# How to center tooltips for block elements with CSS or JS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to create a custom `Tooltip` component where the direction of the tooltip is passed via a prop:

```
Hello, <Tooltip>Right tooltip (Hover).</Tooltip>
```

I made this component, which works fine with inline elements, has position issues when it comes to a component with `block` elements:

```
Hello, <Tooltip><div className="box">This has click event tooltip with a block element.</div></Tooltip>
```

The issue is when a tooltip has a `block` element as its child, the tooltip misaligns and completely breaks.

Is there an approach where the tooltip can be positioned on the center edge of the component, just like how it works with inline text?

How can I fix this?

Comment: what r u trying to do? do u want to align the tooltip at the centre of the block ?

Comment: Yes, @AmareshSM for right, left, bottom, top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed  `margin-bottom: 0;` to `margin-bottom: -6px;` for tooltip triangle to plced in center of tooltip edge.

```
[data-tooltip-dir="left"]:before {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: -12px;
  margin-bottom: -6px;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: #000;
  border-left-color: hsla(0, 0%, 20%, 0.9);
}

[data-tooltip-dir="right"]:before {
  margin-bottom: -6px;
  margin-left: -12px;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: #000;
  border-right-color: hsla(0, 0%, 20%, 0.9);
}
```

then

```
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-meadow-q2zyw?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) containing the fixed version.hope to solve your problem!

**Update**

For Next.js and style jsx

accesing to data-attribute in `<style jsx>` is a bit different.insted of
`[data-tooltip-dir="left"]` you should use class name in front of [] like this
`.tooltip[data-tooltip-dir="left"]`

temporary [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/next-js-1ddom)

Comment: Wait, wow. This works, I think. I need to test it in production, but this seems good. I don't understand how this fixed it. Weird.

Comment: I'm not sure why but when I add this to my actual code, the tooltip sticks to the bottom of the element.  https://i.imgur.com/DZU68Y7.png

The only difference is that the tooltip is wrapping a <a> element. I also removed all of the styling, and the problem still consist. Any ideas why this would happen?

Comment: Actually, after some testing it seems that the css for this works great, if the css is in it's own style.css file. However,  if I was to add this to a <style jsx> block, it breaks. hmm.

Comment: seems like this is a next/jsx issue. https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-thunder-k6hsp

Comment: it's not an issue, don't worry. please update your question